# Parsing JSON data with javascriptserializer throws exception

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I am getting JSON data in following format:

```
"[[\"NAME\",\"state\"],\n[\"Alabama\",\"01\"],\n[\"Alaska\",\"02\"]]"
```

I am trying to parse it with `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` the following way:

```
 [Serializable]
 private class State
 {
     private string Name { get; set; }
     private string Code { get; set; }
 }


  private static List<State> getStates(string jsonData)
  {          
     var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     var parsedResult = json.Deserialize<List<State>>(jsonData);
     return parsedResult;
  }
```

The error I am getting is `Type 'State' is not supported for deserialization of an array.`
What am I doing wrong?Please suggest a way out.

**Update**

I have somewhat solved the problem since I need only a collection of the data in a queryable format. The following code did the trick:

```
var parsedResult = json.Deserialize<List<string[]>>(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have found workaround, nevertheless I think it's good to have explanation for the issue.

The problem you have is in brackets; `[]` means array, whereas object is market with `{}`. This means that to deserialize input string in array of `State` objects your input string should be formatted in following way:

```
[{\"NAME\",\"state\"},\n{\"Alabama\",\"01\"},\n{\"Alaska\",\"02\"}]
```